# vim identify window

Tags: function, vim, window

I have a function which opens a new window containing the results of a script

```
function! MyFunc()
    bo new
    se buftype=nofile
    silent! exec "r! sh MyScript.sh "
endfunction
```

I'd like to identify this specific window so that I can call my function multiple times and use the same window each time rather than opening a new window.

something like

```
if exists(myWindow) 
    use myWindow
else
    bo new
endif
```

Comment: The window must be unique for the whole editing session?  Or, for one buffer or tab page?

Comment: basically I only want to see one window.  each time I call my function it should use the same window and over write the contents. Or just destroy the window and make a new one.

Comment: Then the approach proposed by @Owen (to use a global variable to store the current state of the custom window) is just right.  By the way, you probably need to watch your custom buffer, not window.  A window is only a display frame for a buffer, so you can't make a window locked to a particular buffer.  What you should do is reopen a window with the same custom buffer (that contains recent script output).

Comment: Also, consider using the preview window, which is sort of designed for this type of task. However, it would be undesirable if you want to be able to use other preview functionality (ptag etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think this might work... but... tread carefully because I am no Vim expert.

When you create the window the first time you can save it in a global:

```
bo new
set buftype=nofile
let g:my_run_buffer = bufnr("%")
```

and subsequently you can check to see if that buffer exists:

```
if bufexists(g:my_run_buffer)
    " Go to buffer
    set swb=usetab
    exec "sbuf " . g:my_run_buffer
else
    ... create it ...
endif
```

Setting "swb=usetab" will mean that when `sbuf` switches to the buffer, it will go to whatever window/tab it is currently open in, if it is open. I don't like setting swb globally like that, just for one sbuf call. Anyone know a better way?

Comment: this is close but I really need to identify a window rather than a buffer.

Comment: @rvabdn: but that window has a buffer in it, doesn't it?

Comment: @rvabdn: You can identify the window number with winnr(), and then when you want to go to it find the visible buffer with winbufnr() then :sbuf to that buffer. But I think this is the same as just going to the buffer number directly, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, your right,  I was getting confused but this actually works just fine.  Thanks!